# JavaScript reader.readAsDataURL() returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, function, base64, blob, filereader

I've been trying to find a way to Base64 encode binary data with JavaScript for the past few hours and it turns out that `btoa()` only works with strings so I came up with the following code, where `blob` is the file I need to encode:

```
function base64Encode(blob) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        console.log(reader.result);
    };
};
```

Problem is, `base64Encode(blob)` always returns `undefined`, does anybody know a fix?

Comment: try just to put your function in onload, not onloadend. Also, is there any chance your blob is malformed?

Comment: Your function `base64Encode` does not return anything, so implicit `undefined` is returned.

Comment: 1. Any function that has no `return` statement “returns undefined”.  2. readAsDataUrl is async.  [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your function, you could use promises and async/await. As an example see the below code, it might help you.

```
const convertBlobToBase64 = async (blob) => {
  return await blobToBase64(blob);
}

const blobToBase64 = blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
  reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});
```

caller:

```
console.log(await convertBlobToBase64(someFileData));
```